# How can I implement a "Select All" checkbox in my ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a table with a column full of checkboxes.  At the top I would like to have a single "Select All" checkbox that would check all the checkboxes on that page.

How should I implement this?  I'm using jQuery as my JavaScript framework if it matters.

Answer (score 16):

This will keep all the individual checkboxes the same as the "check all" one

```
$("#id-of-checkall-checkbox").click(function() {
    $(".class-on-my-checkboxes").attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

This will keep the "check all" one in sync with whether or not the individual checkboxes are actually all checked or not

```
$(".class-on-my-checkboxes").click(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
        $("#id-of-checkall-checkbox").attr('checked', false);
    }
    else if ($(".class-on-my-checkboxes").length == $(".class-on-my-checkboxes:checked").length) {
        $("#id-of-checkall-checkbox").attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks like the else if case doesn't work... it should be setting the checkall checkbox to true when all the sub checkboxes are checked.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think I figured it out... added a space before ":checked" and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

jquery (**EDITED** to toggle check/uncheck all):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggleAll").click(function() {  
      $("#chex :checkbox").attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
    });    
});
```

The reason why I had to do a `click()` then check for `checked` status is because if you try to "`toggle`" a checkbox, the checkbox being toggled will not retain its checked status. This way it retains the check status and effectively toggles.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleAll" />
<div id="chex">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: Those look like ASP.NET checkboxes, not ASP.NET-MVC. MVC would just use regular html checkboxes.  How does that change things?

Comment: With this solution, if the user unchecks the 'select all' check box, the boxes stay checked. See my answer below for the jQuery to handle selecting AND deselecting all boxes.

Comment: @kingnestor - it won't change anything. use your standard checkboxes and this will work.

Comment: You should create an example based on table markup where the select all checkbox is present in header row. Current example markup is totally different from what is listed in the question.

Comment: Also, you are using 'paragraph' for toggling whereas the OP wants a checkbox to toggle the state.

Answer (score 3):

For me, Jeremy's solution mostly worked, **but I had to replace** `.attr` with `.prop`. Otherwise once I single clicked on a checkbox it would stop reacting to the "master" checkbox.

**in the _Layout.cshtml (master page)**

```
$(document).ready(
    manageCheckboxGroup('chkAffectCheckboxGroup', 'checkbox-group')
);
```

**in a referenced .js**

```
    function manageCheckboxGroup(masterCheckboxId, slaveCheckboxesClass) {

    $("#" + masterCheckboxId).click(function () {
        $("." + slaveCheckboxesClass).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $("." + slaveCheckboxesClass).click(function () {
        if (!this.checked) {
            $("#" + masterCheckboxId).prop('checked', false);
        }
        else if ($("." + slaveCheckboxesClass).length == $("." + slaveCheckboxesClass + ":checked").length) {
            $("#" + masterCheckboxId).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
}
```

**in the HTML (Razor) page**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input id="chkAffectCheckboxGroup" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Clients[0].ClientId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Clients[0].Name)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Clients.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Clients[i].Id" class="form-control" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Clients[i].Name" />
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" asp-for="Clients[i].Selected" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Clients[i].Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Clients[i].Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**IMPORTANT:**
also, at first I had a `@foreach` loop in the HTML and it did not work..., you must use a `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Clients.Count(); i++)` loop instead otherwise you end up with a empty list in the `OnPostAsync()`.

Answer (score 1):

While the answers posted previously will work, you'll run into issues if you have more than one set of checkboxes in a single page.

This format will work regardless:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Tabular Data 1</td>
            <td>Tabular Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Tabular Data 3</td>
            <td>Tabular Data 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the script...

```
$(function() {
    $('th > :checkbox').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('table')
            .find('td > :checkbox')
            .attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

Comment: that is way more jquery than is needed. mine will work regardless of format so long as the proper selectors are added

Comment: @Jason: I certainly agree the same effect can be accomplished with less code but regardless, the method shown in my answer will allow multiple sets of checkboxes to exist in a single page.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modifying markup from Marve's answer (giving ID to the table)

[Working Demo →](http://jsbin.com/ubehi)

**EDIT:**

Updated version where the 'selectAll' checkbox correctly reflects the state of the checkboxes. E.g. if you select all checkboxes manually, selectAll checkbox will automatically get checked. Try the demo to understand the behavior.

Code:

```
<table id='myTable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Tabular Data 1</td>
            <td>Tabular Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Tabular Data 3</td>
            <td>Tabular Data 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Your jQuery could be as simple as this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('#myTable th input:checkbox').click(
            function() 
            {
                $('#myTable td input:checkbox').attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
            }
        );

        //The following code keeps the 'selectAll' checkbox in sync with
        //the manual selection of the checkboxes by user. This is an additional usability feature.
        $('#myTable tr input:checkbox').click(
            function()
            {
                var checkedCount = $('#myTable td input:checkbox:checked').length;
                var totalCount = $('#myTable td input:checkbox').length;
                $('#myTable th input:checkbox').attr('checked', checkedCount === totalCount);
            }
        );
    }
 );
```

Comment: Same as my comment above... this didn't work for me until I put a space before the ":checked" selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this For HTML table.

```
<table class="rptcontenttext" style="width: 100%; border-style: solid; border-collapse: collapse"  
         border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
         <thead>  
           <tr>  
             <th style="text-align:left;width:10px;">  
             <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="chkVerifySelection" id="chkVerifySelection" onchange="return     checkAllVerifySelection();" />  
             </th>  
             <td class="rptrowdata" align="left">  
               Employee ID  
             </td>  
           </tr>  
         </thead>  
         <tbody style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; max-height: 400px; width: 100%;">  
             @for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmployeeInformationList.Count; i++)  
             {      
           <tr>  
             <td style="width:10px">    
               @{  
               if (Model.EmployeeInformationList[i].SelectStatus==true)  
                 {  
                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeInformationList[i].SelectStatus, new { @class = "VerifyStatus" ,disabled =                  "disabled",@checked="checked" })   
                 }  
                 else  
                    {  
                   @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeInformationList[i].SelectStatus, new { @class = "VerifyStatus" })   
                    }  
                 }        
            </td>             
             <td class="rptrowdata" align="left" style="width: 70px">  

               @Html.Encode(Model.EmployeeInformationList[i].StrEmpID)   

             </td>  
              <td class="rptrowdata" align="center" style="width: 50px">  
               @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.EmployeeInformationList[i].strEmpOldCardNo)  
                @Html.Encode(Model.EmployeeInformationList[i].strEmpOldCardNo)  
             </td>  
           </tr>  
             }  
         </tbody>  
       </table>
```

Script:

```
 function checkAllVerifySelection() {  
     var flag = $('input[name=chkVerifySelection]').is(':checked');  
     if (flag) {  
       $(".VerifyStatus").each(function () {  
         $(this).attr('checked', true);  
       });  
     }  
     else {  
       $(".VerifyStatus").each(function () {  
         $(this).attr('checked', false);  
       });  
     }  
     return true;  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
@Html.CheckBox("CheckAll", false, new { id = "select_all" })
$('#select_all').click(function () {
    $('.someClass').prop('checked', this.checked)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {  
        $(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));  
    });  
    $(".checkBoxClass").change(function(){  
        if (!$(this).prop("checked")){  
            $("#ckbCheckAll").prop("checked",false);  
        }  
    }) 
});
```